# JWT Authentication Error "Invalid Signature" in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm new to Python and Django REST Framework and I'm trying to configure authentication using JWT (https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/). I'm able to create a token for a user upon registration however I'm getting an "Invalid Signature" error when I try to authenticate through my api. I have confirmed the error at https://jwt.io/. This seems to mean my token is being created improperly. Any Ideas?

This is my configuration:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')

from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'phone', 
'password')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # the create method creates and saves an object in a single statement
        user = User.objects.create(
            first_name = validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name = validated_data['last_name'],
            username = validated_data['username'],
            phone = validated_data['phone'],
            password = make_password(validated_data['password']),
        )

        return user

from joyrides_api.models import User
from joyrides_api.serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework_jwt.utils import jwt_payload_handler
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication

class UserList(APIView):

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    # this method creates the user
    def post(self, request, format=None):
            serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                # the save method calls serializer's create method
                user = serializer.save()
                if user:
                    jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
                    jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
                    payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
                    token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
                    json = serializer.data
                    json['token'] = token
                    return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to specify `authentication_classes` as well.
Let it be empty and it should work.

Comment: I do have authentication classes for JWT set on my auth routes as I believe that's their utility. I did try setting it on my create token route and still received an invalid signature.

Comment: if i understand correctly, you are successfully gettting the token from this `UserList` view but cannot use that token on other views(getting "invalid signature")?

Comment: I can get a token from the view however the signature is invalid. I double checked the token using the validator at https://jwt.io/ (you can paste an encoded token on the front page and it outputs the contents). The header and payload are correct but the signature is invalid.

Comment: okay, i checked that with my own JWT token. it does say invalid signature.
But it would work with the api.
i think the reason behind "invalid Signature" is that we have `JWT_PUBLIC_KEY` and  `JWT_PRIVATE_KEY` set as None.
If we would state the keys according to `cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPublicKey` and `cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPrivateKey`, we can get the signature verified.

Comment: Yep. I was just able to successfully authenticate with a user using the createsuperuser method. It has something to do with how my user model is interacting with the jwt framework.

Comment: Thank dude, 100 for you

Comment: Thanks for th answer!

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was when I created my users using the django.db.model create method:

```
from . models import User

def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            first_name = validated_data['first_name'],
            ...
        )

        return user
```

I wasn't also creating a user in the Django user model at django.contrib.auth.models which is the model Django and the JWT framework use for authentication. This isn't all that straightforward for a beginner and I'm kind of surprised this isn't a bigger issue considering the popularity of JWT with Django (or so it seemed). I suppose anyone would tell me I should have spent more time in the docs.

I digress, the elegant fix is to customize your user model by extending django.contribut.auth.models' AbstractUser which (I believe) links the pertinent parts of your user model to Django's model. Instructions here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/

The option I did to get this up and running (although I plan on switching to a custom model soon) is to save your user object to the Django user model using django.contrib.auth.models' create_user method which operates identical to the create method above except it saves to Django's user model.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the 'Invalid Signature' error comes up when I create a custom User model. I resolved this by:

1. Instantiating a model based on Django's User model:

``

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    .....
```

``

2. In settings.py, use AUTH_USER_MODEL to point to the custom user model.

``

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.User'
```

``

where 'user.User' points to User model in user app.

Proceed with token generation. The token will validate now.